# Real Time Validation is not working after obtaining page from ajax post

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, validation, real-time

There is a concept of real time validation(RTV) in use in the project that I am currently working in.

**How RTV Works :**

This is pretty straight forward. When the user enters a value in an input element, the value is send to server side code(java in my case) , where it is validated and the response is sent back , which is then appended to the original page.

**Currently:**

We are changing this. Previously, we used to do a form post after form submit. Now when the user clicks a submit button, we will be posting via ajax. So if the post returns a HTML page , with field errors, then that page will be shown back to the user, so that he/she can enter valid input in the fields.

**What's happening instead ?**

I noticed a peculiar thing, after the form post via ajax, when i get back the page and then enter valid input in the field for RTV, the data sent back to my java servlet is empty. The data that i am entering is not going to the servlet for the particular field, though the post is hitting the servlet.

Any ideas why this may be happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

1. Is the server returning the form with correct input field names?
2. Does the AJAX still work after you get form back from server, or does it do a normal POST?
3. Does the JavaScript recognize any of the input fields on the second try? Try adding console.log($("name_of_input")) when you do the submit and see the result in Developer Console in your browser (That is if you're using jQuery. You can also just do document.getElementsByName("name_of_input") )

Would be a lot easier to figure out with some code. Could you show us?